# How exactly do people (accidentally) end up here on MSE?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, asking-questions, statistics

On a daily basis, MSE gets a few (sometimes more than a few) off-topic questions that are posted here by accident. This is when a user intends to post the question on a *specific* site on the network but ends up posting it here instead. It's a pretty common issue that most/all meta regulars probably know about it. There's even a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8122/80115) called 'Saviour' of Lost Souls by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) dedicated to tackling this problem, and it's being used by a number of users already.

I have tried to figure out exactly how those "lost souls" (specifically those who just created an account on the *correct* site)<sup>1</sup> end up on MSE by accident but I can't seem to find the answer.

What's puzzling about this is that, as far as I can tell, there are no direct links to MSE on the homepage of other sites besides <s>a) the "Feedback" link (which is in the footer, so not that visible) and b)</s> the "Featured on Meta" section (which would be surprising if it's attracting that many new users who are coming for the sole purpose of asking a question). It feels like there might be some other path that leads here. Maybe something only presented to new users?

So, does SE keep track of how people end up here? Is this data available somewhere? And is there anything that can be done to stop new users from accidentally switching sites? Maybe warn them when they're about to?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In my experience, there are two other groups of "lost souls": 1) users with no account on any site on the network. 2) users with an *old* account on one of the sites. But I'm mostly interested in the third group mentioned above because it's the one that's most puzzling to me.</sub>

Comment: "Saviour" doesn't tackle the problem of these questions being asked, it only tackles the problem of getting theses questions closed/deleted; it's a cure rather than a prevention.

Comment: Well in a sense it reduces the effort of taking care of this.

Comment: We do link to Meta in some help center articles that new users frequently see. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: There are also many who get question banned or limited on a site, the message they get refers them to t he FAQ here as well, so they read it, and decide to simply ask their question here. I'd guess those are at least 20% of the cases.